# SVG to PDF not working properly in Rails 5.0

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, pdf, svg

The first image below is the "Browser view", and the second one is the "PDF view".

The SVG to PDF is not working properly, I am setting `stroke-dashoffset` value dynamically and is working fine on browser, but when I generate PDF then it doesn't work.

**Browser View**

[image]

**PDF View**

[image]

And here is the code I have used:

**CSS**

```
.svg circle {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  //transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s linear;
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: 1em;
}
.svg .bar {
  stroke: #33aaa3;
}
.cont {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.cont:after {
    border-radius: 100%;
    content: attr(data-pct) "%";
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    height: 160px;
    left: 50%;
    line-height: 160px;
    margin-left: -80px;
    margin-top: -80px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    width: 160px;
}
.col-xs-3 > p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<% if @skills.present? %>
            <div class="filter_group skills_area">
                <h2 class="filter_title">SKILLS</h2>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <% @count = 1 %>
                        <% @skills.each do |skill| %>
                            <div class="col-xs-3 ">
                                <div class="cont" id="cont-<%= @count %>" data-pct="100">
                                    <svg class="svg"  width="200" height="200" viewPort="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                      <circle r="90" cx="100" cy="100" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="565.48" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="#33aaa3"></circle>
                                      <circle class="bar"  r="90" cx="100" cy="100" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="565.48" stroke-dashoffset="0"></circle>
                                    </svg>
                                </div>
                                <p><%= skill.title %></p>
                            </div>
                        <% @count += 1 %>
                        <% end %>   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% end %>
```

**jQuery**

```
<% @count = 1 %>
    <% @skills.each do |skill| %>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var val = <%= current_user.profile ? rating_by_skill(current_user.profile.id, skill.id) ?  number_with_precision(rating_by_skill(current_user.profile.id, skill.id), :precision => 2) : 0 : 0 %> * 20;
            var $circle = $('#cont-'+<%= @count %>).find('.svg .bar');

            if (isNaN(val)) {
            val = 0; 
            }
            else{
            var r = $circle.attr('r');
            var c = Math.PI*(r*2);

            if (val < 0) { val = 0;}
            if (val > 100) { val = 100;}

            var pct = ((100-val)/100)*c;
            //alert(pct);
            $circle.css({ strokeDashoffset: pct});

            $('#cont-'+<%= @count %>).attr('data-pct',val);
            }
        });
    </script>
    <% @count += 1 %>
    <% end %>
```

I am using Rails 5.

Comment: How are you rendering the PDF? The JavaScript is not getting executed by whatever method you are using to render the PDF.

Comment: @JasonYost i am using this -->                                                       
pdf = PDFKit.new("#{WEBSITE_URL}/employee/resume/download?id=#{current_user.id}", :page_size => 'A3')

send_data(pdf.to_pdf)

Comment: PDFKit is ruby gem based wkhtmltopdf. First of all, try to install wkhtmltox's last version sable. see here : http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf ? I have used it for almost same functionality as of yours but It was a canvas in browser not SVG.

Comment: @JasonYost hi, If the javascript is not working then how the values coming up correctly in all the four circles, i.e. 90%, 0%, 0% and 0%, it is showing with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help you https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/prawn-ruby/kiiUAV_IFpE

Prawn pdf is very handy for any sort of custom pdf generation

http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf

http://prawnpdf.org/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Graphics.html

Answer (score 0):

As Jason Yost already mentioned, the JavaScript will not be executed by the PDF converter. I am not aware of any PDF converter who executes JavaScript, so I would try to replace the JavaScript with server side code which already produces the correct SVG.

**Update:**

So, the goal of your javascript it to update the `strokeDashoffset` of the second circle. The javascript seems to do it through an inline style, but there also seems to be an attribute for it...

```
<svg class="svg"  width="200" height="200" viewPort="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle r="90" cx="100" cy="100" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="565.48" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="#33aaa3"></circle>
  <circle class="bar"  r="90" cx="100" cy="100" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="565.48" stroke-dashoffset="0"></circle>
</svg>
```

everything you do between `<%` and `%>` is handled by the server and should be fine for the PDF. So you need to throw away the JavaScript and change your SVG to something like this:

(sorry, I don't know anything about ruby, so treat this as pseudo code)

```
                    <% @count = 1 %>
                    <% @skills.each do |skill| %>
<%
val = current_user.profile ? rating_by_skill(current_user.profile.id, skill.id) ?  number_with_precision(rating_by_skill(current_user.profile.id, skill.id), :precision => 2) : 0 : 0 ;
val = val * 20;

// calculate the percentage the same way as in the javascript...
// and store it in a variable

pct = ((100-val)/100)*c;
%>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 ">
                            <div class="cont" id="cont-<%= @count %>" data-pct="100">
                                <svg class="svg"  width="200" height="200" viewPort="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                  <circle r="90" cx="100" cy="100" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="565.48" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="#33aaa3"></circle>
                                  <circle class="bar"  r="90" cx="100" cy="100" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="565.48" stroke-dashoffset="<%= pct %>"></circle>
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                            <p><%= skill.title %></p>
                        </div>
                    <% @count += 1 %>
                    <% end %>
```

as you can see, I added a "ruby" code block to calculate the value and then replaced original `stroke-dashoffset` with the calculated value.

As this is only pseudo-code, please don't expect it to work, but it should make the concept clearer. Feel free to ask additional questions.

Comment: I the javascript is not working then how the values coming up correctly in all the four circles, i.e. 90%, 0%, 0% and 0%, it is showing with javascript, i am totally confused :(